# Sequence timed events from thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread, qtimer

I need to trigger MIDI notes from  a `QList` of notes:

```
struct Note
{
    int index;
    float time;
    float pitch;
    float volume;
    int channel;
};
//...
QList<Note> Notes;
```

The `Notes` are already sorted by time inside `QList`.

I need a *midiplayer* thread to take the `QList` and output the midi notes in accordance with `Note.time`.

Should I use `QTimer` to schedule the next note or use something else.

How should I take into account that `QList` will change in the main thread and the *midiplayer* will need to update to that?

Comment: Will `Notes` be added at the end only or randomly?

Comment: Randomly. When QList with notes is updated the player will continue from the current time. At the end of QList the player might loop again.

Comment: You should use a timer, but you should base the timeout on the passage of time from `QElapsedTimer`. I.e. assuming `Note::time` is in ms, you'd do `QTimer::singleShot(note.time - elapsedTimer.elapsed(), Qt::PreciseTimer, ...)`. The time base from the `elapsedTimer` would have to be adjusted if/when too much latency was observed when the slot/functor got invoked, i.e. if `note.time` is sufficiently "far behind" `elapsedTimer.elapsed()` inside the slot. This would determine the behavior on system stalls etc.